# topological 2 fold covering

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Take $Q_n;=\{q_1,q_2,...,q_n\}$ the topological space with n points, paired with the discrete topology.

I need to find a 2-fold covering of $p:Q_4\rightarrow{Q_2}$.

If I defined $Q_4=\{x_1,...,x_4\}$ and $Q_2:=\{y_1,y_2\}$, would the function $p(x_i):=\{y_1$ if $i\in\{1,2\},y_2$ if $i\in\{3,4\}\}$ work as a two fold covering?

I don't clearly understand the requirement that $p^{-1}(U)$, with $U$ some open set in cover of $Q_2$, is a disjoint union of open sets in the cover for $Q_4$.

Comment: You are working with spaces with discrete topology. "Open set" is a void condition in this setting since all subsets are open. So an open neighborhood of $x$ is just a subset that contains $x$ (for instance, the singleton $\{x\}$).

Comment: So the function p is a 2 fold covering? And p is a homeomorphism since the pre image of any open set is open (since, as you said, we're working with the descrete topology)

Comment: It can not be an homeomorphism since an homeomorphism is bijection, but yes, $p$ is a two-fold covering, since $p^{-1}(\{x\})$ is the disjoint union of two singletons for all $x$.

Comment: As I said, homeomorphisms are bijection, here, you have a set with two elements and one with 4 elements, with their discrete topology. There will never be an homeomorphism between them.

Comment: It is ahomeomorphism when restricted to $\{x_1,x_3\}$ or $\{x_2, x_4\}$, so you do have a covering map. Well done!

Comment: Would it be enough to say it is a covering map since, whenever restricted to each $\{x_i\}$ it is a homeomorphism? Since the union of singletons $\{x_i\}$ is a covering of $Q_4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact each surjective map $p : D' \to D$ between discrete spaces is a covering map. To see this, note that each $d \in D$ has $\{d \}$ as an open neighorhood and $p^{-1}(\{d \}) = \bigcup_{d' \in p^{-1}(\{d \})} \{d'\}$ where the $\{d'\}$ are pairwise disjoint open subsets of $D'$ which are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $\{d \}$.

In your example you have a surjection whose fibers have $2$ elements, thus it is a twofold covering map.